# Can I store different values in an object's field depending on the object it is called from?

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm

I work on a genetic algorithm for a robotic assembly line balancing problem (assigning assembly operations and robots to stations to minimize the cycle time for a given number of stations). The solution is represented by an ArrayList (`configuration`) which holds all the operations in the sequence assigned to different stations. Furthermore, I have two more ArrayLists (`robotAssignment`, `operationPartition`) which indicate where a new station starts and which robot is assigned to a station. For example, a solution candidate looks like this (`configuration`, `robotAssignment`, `operationPartition` from top to bottom):

```
Initial cycle time: 50.0
|2|7|3|9|1|5|4|6|8|10|
|2|1|3|2|
|0|2|5|7|
```

From this representation we know that operations 3, 9, and 1 are assigned to station 2 and robot 1 is used since `operationPartition` gives the starting index of a new station in `configuration`.

With the help of the ArrayList `operationPartition` I can always figure out the station of an operation. However, I would prefer to store the station index in the an object of the class `Operation` itself. I created a class `Operation` with a class variable `stationIndex`. All operations are added to another class `OperationManager` which holds all operations in an ArrayList. My class `Configuration` is used to create a new configuration and include all operations from the `OperationManager`.

My problem is that I can store the `stationIndex` of an operation only once and not for each configuration (at least I could not figure how to do this). To give you an example lets assume we have two configurations:

```
    Configuration conf1 = new Configuration();
    Configuration conf2 = new Configuration();
    conf1.generateIndividual();
    conf2.generateIndividual();
```

Now, if I change the `stationIndex` of `operation1`  in `conf1` it is also changed in `conf2` since this variable "belongs" to the operation and does depend on the configuration.

Is there any way to store different values in the `stationIndex` depending on the configuration? This would be my preferred solution if this is somehow possible.

```
public class Operation {
    int[] predecessors;
    int stationIndex;


// Construct an operation with given predecessors
public Operation(int[] predecessors){
    this.predecessors = predecessors;

}


// Get operations's predecessors
public int[] getPredecessors() {
    return this.predecessors;
}

// Set operations's station index
public void setStationIndex(int stationIndex){
    this.stationIndex = stationIndex;
}

// Get operations's station index
public int getStationIndex(){
    return this.stationIndex;
}
```

Class OperationManager:

```
public class OperationManager {

// Holds our operations
private static ArrayList operations = new ArrayList<Operation>();

// Adds an operation
public static void addOperation(Operation operation) {
    operations.add(operation);
}

// Get an operation
public static Operation getOperation (int index){
    return (Operation)operations.get(index);
}

// Get index of an operation
public static int getOperationIndex(Operation operation) {
    return operations.indexOf(operation);
}

// Get the number of operations
public static int numberOfOperations() {
    return operations.size();
}
```

Class Configuration (not complete but with all relevant parts):

```
public class Configuration {

int initialCycleTime = RobotManager.calcLowerBound();

// Holds our array of operations
private ArrayList configuration = new ArrayList<Operation>();
private ArrayList robotAssignment = new ArrayList<Robot>();
private ArrayList operationPartition = new ArrayList<Integer>();

// Cache
private int fitness = 0;

// Constructs a blank configuration
public Configuration() {
    for (int i = 0; i < OperationManager.numberOfOperations(); i++) {
        configuration.add(null);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < GA_RALBP.numberOfStations; i++) {
        operationPartition.add(null);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < GA_RALBP.numberOfStations; i++) {
        robotAssignment.add(null);
    }

}

// Creates a random individual
public void generateIndividual() {
    // Loop over all operations and add them to our configuration
    for (int operationIndex = 0; operationIndex < OperationManager.numberOfOperations(); operationIndex++) {
        setOperation(operationIndex, OperationManager.getOperation(operationIndex));
    }
    // Randomly shuffle the configuration
    Collections.shuffle(configuration);
}
```

Comment: Please provide the full code

Comment: I don't understand the question, but I'm getting a strong feeling you are using static variables when you should not. This line in particular rang alarm bells: *I can store the `stationIndex` of an operation only once and not for each configuration*, which suggests `stationIndex` is a static variable but should be an instance variable of the configuration class.

Comment: What I would like to loop over my population and get the station index of an operation of a certain operation. Something like: `conf1.getOperaration(index).getStationIndex()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either station index is part of an Operation object or not.

If station index *is* part of an Operation object, then you'll need to represent the same operation with multiple `Operation` objects, since you want the Operation object in one configuration to hold a different station index in one configuration than another. You could make that happen in `Configuration.generateIndividual()` by cloning the object you get back from `OperationManager.getOperation()`.

Alternatively, you could remove station index from Operation objects. For example, you could represent the station index by the operation's position in the list in `Configuration`.